# High-res or vector badge icons?

Tags: feature-request, badges, user-interface, top-bar, retina

I recently got a new Apple laptop with my first retina display.  Zounds!  Things are fabulous.

Stack Overflow looks great at this higher resolution, except for the badge icons:  they look rather pixelated, and it doesn't appear to be a intentional stylistic choice.

Could we have nicer badge icons?  I'm not asking for a new look, just a circle that looks more, well, *circular*.

Comment: Didn't vote yet, but is this really needed?  I mean, it's a simple filled circle.  It's not as if they're achievements with special icons like in a game.

Comment: The simple SVG circle would be delightful: what I have now is a pile of discrete blocks.

Comment: I asked if it was really needed, "its cool" isn't a reason.

Comment: I get the sense that it would be about an hour of work: craft the images, drop them into the right spot in the static assets and wait for them to go out on the next deploy.  I agree it's not essential, but I also expect it would be easy to implement.

Comment: Related: [HDPI version of Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161373/hdpi-version-of-stack-exchange)

Comment: I get the sense that the "hour of work" would be an hour better spent somewhere else where it actually matters. Why do you care if the little badge indicators are smooth? Does it increase their value? I frankly rarely notice them, much less inspect them for image quality.

Comment: How do they look on [scifi.se] or [android.se]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The badges have been updated! Thank you.